# A fan that idolizes someone because he is hot at that momment and many people idolize him

Tags: word-request

I want a single word  to describe a person who became a fan of somebody just because that one is very famous at that time and many people admire him, but not because she loves him.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a word for this exact definition, but there are similar words you can use:

- A leech – someone who uses someone else's influence for their own
  gain
- A vessel – someone who has no opinions of their own and just follows
  what is popular
- A drone – same as vessel
- A bandwagon fan – usually used in sports, but means someone who only
  supports a sports team because they are succeeding

Answer (score 0):

A **groupie** is attracted to the lifestyle and fame, more than recognizing or appreciating talent. Groupie is specifically a (female) fan who tries to get backstage, or follows a music act while they are on tour, but the term is applied broadly as an insult to any similar star-chasing behavior.

A **poser** (poseur) goes along with the crowd to fit in.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an exact fit, but you might refer to them as a ***[fair-weather](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fair-weather)*** fan:

> 1 : loyal only during a time of success
>   *// a fair-weather friend*
>   <sub>*definition from [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fair-weather)*</sub>